# Navigation Bar gone

Tags: ios, swift, segue, appdelegate

How can I present a view controller from my AppDelegate and have a Navigation bar added to that view with a back button to the previous view? I need to do this programmatically from my AppDelegate. Currently I can push a controller from there, but it doesn't act like a segue. It doesn't add a nav bar with a back button. Now I know I should be able to add one myself, but when I do it gets hidden. Currently I'm using `pushViewController()`, but I imagine that's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I had something that I think is similar, if not the same:

**HIGH LEVEL VIEW**

  The general composition of my App (thus far, and specific to the issue at hand -
  *note: details about classes provided for context, not required for resolution*
  ) is as follows:
  - `UIViewController` (ViewController.swift) *embedded* in a `UINavigationController`
  - Buttons on `UIViewController` segue to a view with a custom class:

    - `ExistingLocationViewController` - subclass of:

      - `UITableViewController`
  - One of the buttons (**Add New Location**) in the `UINavigationController`'s Toolbar segues to view with another custom class:

    - `NewLocationViewController` - subclass of:

      - `UIViewController`
      - `CLLocationManagerDelegate`
      - `UITextFieldDelegate`
  - There are a number of other items here, but I believe the above is sufficient as the foundation for the issue at hand

      [image]

**RESOLUTION**

  In order to preserve the navigation-bar (and tool-bar) going both forward and back - I have the following code in my custom classes (
  *note: the following is Swift-3 code, you may have to adjust for Swift-2*
  ):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden       = false 
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated) // #=# not sure if this is needed
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden       = false
}
```

You could actually omit the last two lines in `viewWillDisappear`, or perhaps even omit the entire `override` function
The net result (for me) was as depicted below:

  [image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add a `NavigationController` in `appDelegate` you can do it like this,in this way,your viewcontroller is load from storyboard

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc") as! ViewController
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```